# Need this particular jar file

Tags: java, api, jar, bing

I am trying to connect to the bing api through my java application and query bing programmatically. And I found this page online that gives me sample code to just get a feel of how to go about the entire process. But I am unable to compile and run that code because it has two imports namely

```
com.microsoft.schemas.livesearch._2008._03.search.LiveSearchServiceStub;
com.microsoft.schemas.livesearch._2008._03.search.LiveSearchServiceStub.*;
```

Could anybody give me a link to get these jar files.

I already googled it, checked sourceforge and everything. So If anyone knows of another site that definitely has this jar file, or if you have a copy of these two jar files please do let me know how I can obtain them. It would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Follow steps @ http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/

Answer (score 0):

By the names of those classes they are just Stub classes, meaning they are just dummy-versions of the classes without any real functionality. You can probably just create your own easily.

Answer (score 0):

Bing provides it search services via Web Services. You can access them from any language that provides a web services interface (or just web access).

[Bing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251072.aspx)